# Angular 7 SSR loading first time twice

Tags: angular, angular-universal, server-side-rendering

I have several sites built in `Angular 7` with `SSR` for `SEO` improvements. All apps themselves are fine however it always happens that either **the very first time** or when you perform a **hard refresh** there is this small *blip* whereby all content is shown and suddenly the site itself "reloads".

All conditions for `ngIf`'s that may hide components that are evaluated in the `ngOnInit` section of the components seem to be ignored and animations that may start with `opacity = 0` to hide HTML elements are also shown.

That said I read a lot regarding this in different forums, posts, github issues etc however I haven't been able to get to any solution.

I tried changing the `main.ts` to have:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
});
```

instead of the classic bootstrap mechanism for no joy. I have tried the option for the `initialNavigation` enabled in the `AppRouting` but still doesn't work:

```
@NgModule({
    exports: [ RouterModule ],
    imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {enableTracing, scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled', initialNavigation: 'enabled'}) ],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

I read through the issue here which I thought it may be related:
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/7477 but it ends referring to the initialNavigation flag which hasn't worked for me.

I'm not sure if there is anything else that I could try here or anything "special" to be set up but it would be really nice to have no delay or hide the actual rendered page which is causing the navigation to be a bit less friendly.

Note that this is JUST on the first load, first time load or hard refresh. The rest of the navigation is absolutely fine.

Comment: Did you use TransferState?

Comment: I have configured TransferHttpCacheModule in the app.module and ServerTransferStateModule in the app.server.module. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes, that module is using TransferState. Using that solved my flickering problem, so I thought it could be the same for you

Comment: Thought so too... thanks anyway. It did resolve a duplicate http call though

Comment: Hey @CarlosTorrecillas, I'm having the same issue, I have a landing page with an intro, and every hard refresh, the animation starts, and then stops and restarts again because of the ssr. How did you solve your solution?

Comment: Hi @EliyaCohen, I tried different things such as the initialNavigationEnabled: true and making sure the ServerTransferState and BrowserTransferState modules were set up properly. Other than that I have seen that happening from time to time and I have been updating to the latest versions of angular / universal but no luck. I guess you could do something like "display: none" by default then remove it after a short while (haven't tried it though) but I'm not sure about the impact of it on SEO. To be honest in most cases I have ended up accepting it - and never felt better!

Answer (score 3):

Actually the flicker occurs because the server side of your app is first loaded by the browser and the client then subsequently loaded. Therefore, a quick workaround I implemented was to add a "display: none" on the landing page for the server side only.

To implement, wrap your main component in a  tag and add a conditional display clause to it. I will suggest you do this only on your landing page. Using bootstrap 4, this is what your the main layout should look like:

*app.layout.html*

```
<div  [className]="!display?'d-none':''">
    <app-navbar current_page="post"></app-navbar>
    <router-outlet ></router-outlet>
    <app-footer></app-footer>
</div>
```

Take note of the **[className]="!display?'d-none':''"**

and in the component.ts file:

*app.component.ts*

```
import {Component, Inject, OnInit, PLATFORM_ID} from '@angular/core';
import {isPlatformBrowser} from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-layout',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  display = true;
  constructor( @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object) {
    if (!isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
      this.display = false;
    }
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  onActivate(event) {

  }
}
```

Like I mentioned, its a workaround that actually works.

Comment: Thanks for this. I wonder what would be impact in the actual SEO because the site would be rendered as display:none ? Am I right?

Comment: Yes, you are likely right. Thats why I recommended doing it only on the landing page. You can go further to hide it on popular browsers only (e.g. by checking the user-agent), hence might not be hidden to the crawler bots. You can also set a timeout so that the content of the page becomes visible after a certain period say 10 seconds. These I believe should limit the impact on SEO.

Comment: This is like the worst thing to do, you are literally fighting the purpose of SSR

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and my solution was to enable ssr only for crawlers (google, yahoo, facebook...).

```
// server.ts
// All regular routes use the Universal engine
server.get('*', (req, res) => {
  // serve ssr only to web crawlers
  if((/(google|bing|yahoo|slurp|facebot|duckduck)/gi).test(req.headers['user-agent'])){
      res.render(indexHtml, {
        req,
        providers: [{provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: req.baseUrl}]
    });
  }
  else{
    res.sendFile(join(distFolder, 'index.html'));
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I only need the SSR for crawlers and this is the perfect solution.

Comment: @YKTan How can you test if your approach works properly?

Comment: @Nour-eddine Taleb How did you test your approach? I mean, I can never pretend to be google or any other crawler. How can I ensure that it works properly?

Comment: @user1419243 well you can just pretend you are google for example you can run this: curl -H "user-agent: Googlebot" https://yourwebsite . this should return the ssr rendering(html). but if you use your default agent like a web brower you will get just javascript (no ssr)