# Angular: homepage is rendering for a second before loading different route, even after I delete the contents of the homepage component template

Tags: angular, nginx, caching

I have a landing page using the pathname /private-howzatgolf-cookalong. Whenever I go to that path on our site, I can see the homepage briefly render on the screen for a second before loading the actual landing page.

I also noticed if I completely delete the contents of the homepage component template and I navigate to the homepage route, I still can see the old homepage flash on the screen for a second.

This happens even if I point a completely different domain name to the site.

I am not sure what is causing this. I would like for there to be nothing rendered on the screen until each route has finished loading completely.

Bear in mind this only happens with certain routes, not all of them.

Here is the app.routing.ts file: https://pastebin.com/qzgJNNn1

I have already tried pointing the homepage ('' in the router file) to the HowzatLandingPageComponent, and had the same result.

Also tried removing the last line in the Routes array in that file. It did not fix the problem:

```
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
```

This issue does not happen when the site is served locally, it only happens after the app is built and hosted on a server using nginx.

Comment: can you provide code in stackbliz.

Comment: { path: '', component: LandingComponent, pathMatch: 'full'}

Answer (score 1):

I found a fix for it. We're using server side rendering which was causing the homepage to briefly flicker before Angular handled routing.

More details in the first answer of this post:

[Angular 7 SSR loading first time twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55126790/angular-7-ssr-loading-first-time-twice)